# Как сделать так, чтобы изменения были видны только в ветке new_branch?

Tags: git

Я гит знаю плохо (очень плохо), поэтому извиняйте за тупой вопрос.

Сейчас я нахожусь на ветке master с внесенными изменениями. Я понимаю, что я не смогу исправить эту проблему прямо сейчас, поэтому я хочу их перенести в другую ветку, которую я сейчас создам и скрыть от посторонних глаз.

То есть:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Теперь я на ветке new_branch. Как сделать так, чтобы изменения были видны только в ветке new_branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Теперь вам просто нужно закоммитить (сохранить) изменения

```
git add . 
git commit -am "Some commit description"
```

после чего можете переключиться обратно на `master`

```
git checkout master
```

Для изучения git'а совеутю прочесть эту книгу: [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/ru). Она небольшая, и написана доступным языком.

Если какие-то моменты будут непонятны, то главное не ступориться и читать дальше, а к пропущенному материалу можно вернуться позже.

Comment: Спасибо :) Буду читать книгу, чтобы больше не задавать глупых вопросов.

Comment: Вопрос не глупый, все когда-то начинали ;)

Answer (score 0):

Если изменения еще не попали ни в какой коммит, просто сделайте

```
git add .
git commit -m 'недоделанные изменения'
```

в ветке `new_branch`

Если коммит с изменениями уже существует в обоих ветках, нужно откатить его в мастере, например так:

```
git reset --hard master^
```

Comment: Не показывайте новичкам команду `reset` :)